# Using Harbor Helm with RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, kubernetes-helm, harbor

Is it possible to use Harbor Helm with RDS?

The original installation of Harbor, without using Helm Charts and Kubernetes, involves a harbor.yml that requires 4 databases to be set up: Harbor Core, Clair, Notary Server, and Notary Signer.

I have been told that using Harbor Helm requires these databases to be set up and managed. Therefore, when using Harbor Helm, that installs Harbor in a Kubernetes Cluster, do we still need these 4 databases to be set up and configured? If so, should RDS be used?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do, We are using Postgres via RDS which is deployed via terraform.  I then
updated the Harbor Helm Chart via Kustomize to inject an initContainer.

The initContainer then executes the following script which is passed the 4 database names registry, clair, notary_signer, notary_server

```
 #!/bin/bash
echo "Creating Databases: $@"
for var in "$@"
do
  select="SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = '$var'"
  create="CREATE DATABASE $var;"
  echo "psql -h <%=database.external.host%> -U postgres -tc \"$select\""
  psql -h <%=database.external.host%> -U postgres -tc "select 1 from pg_database where datname = '$var';" | grep -q 1 || psql -h <%=database.external.host%> -U postgres -tc "$create"
done
```

It sort of stinks that Postgres does not have CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS like CockroachDB does.